# How to debug ExtJS in IE8

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-8, extjs

i'm trying to debug an ExtJS application using IE8 but the file ext-all-debug.js it's too big for the internal IE8 debugger and takes ages to load the code, is there any faster Javascript debugger for IE8 ? Another solution that i came up with is to include every extjs file instead of the big ext-all-debug.js but i cant't find the full list (and order) of the files merged into ext-all-debug.js

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cant't find the full list (and order) of the files merged into ext-all-debug.js

Here you go: http://code.google.com/p/extjs-public/source/browse/extjs-3.x/include/ext.jsb2

Search for ext-all.js.

This file is actually part of the [JSBuilder](http://www.sencha.com/products/jsbuilder/) tool which helps you create a custom version of ext-all.js with just the files you need.

**Edit:** I generated a [copy-and-paste list of the 3.2.1 includes](http://pastebin.org/420806)

Answer (score -1):

FireBug for FireFox.  You don't have to really test your application in IE8 so I suggest FireBug.  If you really want to, you can use FireBug Lite.  JS Lint to detect syntax problems.

Comment: Whereas I'd agree you can develop and debug quite happily in Firefox/Firebug, I think you'd be brave not to test against IE8 for a production system. In the real world, most people still run IE*.

Comment: Case in point - just found a bug in my app where a grid cell holding a date value is blank under IE*, works for everything else.

Comment: I'm using FireBug for development and it's great! but i have some IE only bugs that i have to fix. IE8 internal debugger it's really really slow with the ext-all-debug.js file because it's too big, so i want to include each file separately but i can't find the list of files included in ext-all.js

Comment: This probably wont help, but I use Visual Studio 2008. The freebie version does not offer Javascript debugging which is a shame since its debugger is great.  

If you work for a company, get them to buy it - once license will not kill them. If you work for yourself, it's a harder call.

Comment: In a framework world, the browser differences in the JS engine have been abstracted.  The only real bug I have is when I leave a dangling "," somewhere in code.  That's where JS Lint comes in.

Comment: Yes, frameworks aren't perfect.  Did you format the date in the store and the grid properly?

Comment: The IE problem I just fixed turned out to be a different in the way that IE and Firefox convert datetimes. It was an edge case of probably invalid data, but IE returned null and Firefox just returned the wrong value. This was a case where the underlying Javascript engine was at fault. Not everything lives in the framework.

Comment: I get errors when closing an Ext dialog only on IE. Anything else works. I feel that taking into account, the level of amateurism, crappyness, bugs and pure agony IE causes to developers, and also considering the track record of IE as well as the huge piles of money this browser has cost to companies all over the world, Microsoft should be prohibited to ever make a web browser again, ever! No matter how many chances they got, they always blew it beyond belief! I am so totally fed up with IE and I no longer support it. My users either use something else or go elsewhere. Frak it, really!